# Kafka manually confirmed the message confused

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

1. The producer sends 1, 2, 3, 4 messages in turn, and 1, 2, and 3 are not confirmed.
2. When the consumer restarts, he/she will repeat consumption 1, 2 and 3. The consumer sends a message 4 and the consumer confirms it
3. The consumer will not receive 1, 2 or 3 again after the restart

Is there a mechanism for Kafka to retain an unidentified 1, 2, 3?

Or do you have to process the messages yourself

Answer (score 0):

That's the way Kafka works; individual records are not confirmed; there is just a committed offset within each partition for each consumer.

You can seek to the beginning of the partition, but you will get 1, 2, 3, and 4 as well.